# How to get Column Value for a given Row within GridView using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, I have a row index in a javascript function. Now I want to get the value of a Column for that index in a GridView using javascript. 
Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Please show us the generated html in relation to you question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out...

```
 var tbl = document.getElementById('Gridview1');

 var tbl_row = tbl.rows[parseInt(RowIndex) + 1];

 var tbl_Cell = tbl_row.cells[no of the cell];

 var value= tbl_Cell.innerHTML.toString();
```

Here `no of the cell` indicates the column number.

If it is a template field,you can try this..

```
var value=document.getElementById('GridViewId_ColumnID_' + RowIndex).value;
```

Comment: Its working fine. But I want to get the value at this variable value in your code. How to do this.

Comment: The variable 'value' has the value of the paricular cell..Is it a template feild?

Comment: yes template field.
alert(value); is coming.
<span
id="GridViewId_ColumnID_0">Pending</span>

I want to get the value at this id , in my case its Pending.

Comment: alert(value); is coming undefined :(

Comment: I have edited the answer..var value=document.getElementById('GridViewId_ColumnID_' + RowIndex).value;

Comment: yes, I have tried that too.
var value = document.getElementById('GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId_LabelStatusPendingPOSId_0').value;
alert(value);

Comment: Is it a label..?var value = document.getElementById('GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId_LabelStatusPendingPOSI‌​d_0').innerHTML; alert(value);

Answer (score 1):

**A simple example.**

```
 function myfunc   {
         var b=document.getElementById("GridView1");
         var c=document.getElementById("TextBox1");
         var d=document.getElementById("TextBox2");
         dd=dd+1;
         c.value=document.getElementById("GridView1").rows[dd].cells[2].innerHTML;
         d.value=document.getElementById("GridView1").rows[dd].cells[3].innerHTML;
    }
```

**Get the id of the grid**. Then you play around it by using `rows[]` and `cells[]`

Answer (score 0):

Code behind page :

```
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "callFunctions('" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')");

           // e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
        }
    }
```

Javascript :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function callFunctions(i) {
        //alert('Welcome');
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var tbl = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            var tbl_row = tbl.rows[parseInt(i) + 1];
            var tbl_Cell = tbl_row.cells[0];
            var value = tbl_Cell.innerHTML.toString();
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = value;
        }
        window.close();
    }

</script>
```

If EnableEventValidation error occurring mean set its                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                EnableEventValidation="false".